# How can I combine scroll-behavior: smooth with overflow-anchor: auto?

Tags: css

I am attempting to combine [`scroll-behavior: smooth;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) with the [`overflow-anchor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor) CSS property to ensure classic 'stay at the bottom' chat app behavior:

- New message elements appear at the bottom of the chat area.
- When the chat area isn't scrolled all the way down, existing elements stay on screen (ie, no scrolling happens) when new elements are added
- When the chat area is scrolled all the way down, and new elements are added, the chat area scrolls down.

I have the scrolling behavior working - please run the code snippet below - but the scrolling isn't smooth:

```js
let chatArea = document.querySelector('.chat-area');
let anchor = document.querySelector('.anchor');

// https://ajaydsouza.com/42-phrases-a-lexophile-would-love/
let messages = [
  'I wondered why the baseball was getting bigger. Then it hit me.',
  'Police were called to a day care, where a three-year-old was resisting a rest.',
  'Did you hear about the guy whose whole left side was cut off? He’s all right now.'
];

function randomMessage() {
  return messages[(Math.random() * messages.length) | 0];
}

function addMessage() {
  let message = document.createElement('div');
  message.className = 'message';
  message.innerText = randomMessage();
  chatArea.insertBefore(message, anchor);
}
setInterval(addMessage, 1000);
```

```css
.chat-area {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.chat-area * {
  overflow-anchor: none;
}

.anchor {
  overflow-anchor: auto;
  height: 1px;
}

.message {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 6px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-area">
  <!-- new content dynamically inserted here -->
  <div class="anchor"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see from running the code snippet above, everything works it's just like `scroll-behavior: smooth` doesn't seem to be having an effect.

**How can I combine scroll-behavior: smooth with overflow-anchor: auto?**